# Using PHP Mongodb Driver - get Document count

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to find two things, first: a way to know if my query was successful in finding any results, and second: a way to know the number of documents being returned by my query.  The query below runs fine and will return either a document or not as it is using _id as the filter criteria but I'm not always using an exclusive parameter such as _id and may get multiple returns back:

```
$requestID = $_GET["request_id"];
$options = [];
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_GET["request_id"]) ];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$retval = $connection->executeQuery($db_name.'.requests', $query);
```

Ultimately, I want to know - were any records found, and if so, how many.

I've tried

```
if (!empty($retval))
```

which doesn't seem to catch anything, and I have no way to get the count.

Thanks